# How do I debug a Ruby gem? (Compass)

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubygems, compass-sass

I am in the early stages of learning Ruby and want to learn how to debug a gem, but am having trouble finding learning resources around this. A simple example would go a long way for me.

Is [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) the preferred debugger? Where do I require it? How do I set breakpoints with it?

**Note:** I am making an educated guess that the debugging process may be different depending on the gem that needs debugging, so for reference I am particularly interested in [debugging certain issues](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/989) with [Compass](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/).

Comment: There's a difference between RubyGems (the package manager) and a Ruby gem (an individual package). Which do you want to debug?

Comment: Specifically the ruby gem called Compass that I linked to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, figured this out on my own. Here were the steps I took..

I am running Ruby 1.9.3 (determined by running `ruby -v`), so after testing [ruby-debug](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-debug) and [ruby-debug19](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-debug19), I determined these debuggers were no longer maintained, or at least didn't work properly with my install of ruby1.9.3-p125. This lead me to [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger).

The install instructions that worked were:

`$ gem install debugger -- --with-ruby-include=PATH_TO_HEADERS`

The PATH_TO_HEADERS on my machine, was simply the source location of ruby:

`/Users/myusername/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125/`

Since I was particularly determined to debug the Compass compiler, I did the following:

1. Cloned the source: `$ git clone git://github.com/chriseppstein/compass.git`
2. Checked existing compass version first `$ compass -v` which was 13.0
3. Edited VERSION.yml and increased the patch number (to 13.1) so it didn't conflict with my existing install.
4. Edited the .rb of the file I wanted to debug, which was `lib/compass/compiler.rb` and added this line at the top: `require 'debugger'; debugger`
5. Built the gem: `gem build compass.gemspec`
6. Installed the newly compiled gem: `sudo gem install compass-0.13.2.058ead2.gem`
7. Compiled an existing compass based project that I was experiencing problems with, and started debugging.
8. When I was done debugging, I uninstalled the debugging version with `sudo gem uninstall compass` and chose the number corresponding to Compass 13.2.

**Note about step 7:** Since debugger has the same debugging commands as ruby-debug/ruby-debug19, I was able to follow existing tutorials around debugging steps..

- Such as this RailsCast: 
  http://railscasts.com/episodes/54-debugging-with-ruby-debug
- And this blog (and linked cheat sheet):
  http://pivotallabs.com/users/chad/blog/articles/366-ruby-debug-in-30-seconds-we-don-t-need-no-stinkin-gui-

If you have other debugger tutorials, pointers, tips, etc, please post them.